# RSpec tests not using rails app database config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am starting my first ruby on rails project using RSpec and BDD.  When I try to run my rake spec task, I get the following error:

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Clearly rspec is trying to use a default configuration from somewhere and is ignoring the database.yml file in my rails config directory.  How do I fix thi?

Comment: I don't usual call the rake task. Instead I do 'rspec spec' from the application root directory. Does your app work properly in the browser and have you done 'rake db:test:prepare' to setup the test database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I had changed the default configuration for my development and production environments, but had forgotten to change the configuration details for the test environment.